# How can I get data from request where parameters is regex?

Tags: java, java-8

Sorry for my English. I need to filter `List<Contact>` by name using regex and get new `List<Contact>` where name matches regex. Contact has two fields name and id.

For example

```
^B.*$ - returns contacts that do NOT start with B
```

Maybe something like this, but I do not know how to do it by choosing a name and comparing with regex.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("...");

List<String> matching = list.stream()
        .filter(pattern.asPredicate())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can i do this?

Comment: For the specific example “returns contacts that do NOT start with B”, I’d rather use `.filter(contact -> contact.getName().chatAt(0)!='B')`, assuming that contacts generally have a non-empty name…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can filtering `List<Contact>` by its name. for example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("...");

List<Contact> matched = list.stream()
  .filter(it -> it!=null && it.getName()!=null && pattern.matcher(it.getName()).matches())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**OR** using filter chain to make the code more expressive, for example:

```
List<Contact> matched = list.stream()
                            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                            .filter(it -> it.getName() != null)
                            .filter(it -> pattern.matcher(it.getName()).matches())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I'm on mobile you need test by yourself, :).

Comment: if I use it, i get List<String> but not List<Contact>, isn't?

Comment: @alexsafsafsd I'm sorry. I'm on mobile. How about it now?

Comment: @Holger thanks very much, I think it will be print out of the page. just for print purpose.

Comment: thx. however, it doesn't work. In my db exist name - "bbbbbb", and when i use pattern A this contact not accept(

Comment: @alexsafsafsd you can using [CASE_INSENSITIVE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) to cteate a Pattern to matching text ignore case, e.g: `Pattern.compile("regex", CASE_INSENSITIVE)`

Comment: no, you are wrong) obvously, all troubles in this....filter(it -> !pattern.matcher(it.getName()).matches())..... thx, you are super)